# Lazy load of images in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

My app loads a new image from the internet as a background image for the screen when the user taps on a FAB.  I can determine what URL to load prior to the user tapping the screen.

Is there a way to lazy load an image prior to it needing to be displayed by FadeInImage or another Flutter Widget image display mechanism?

Comment: see `ImageProvider`

Comment: Thank you.  Isn't that pretty much what image.network is?  Do you have a snippet of code I can learn from?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/ImageProvider-class.html

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  The code doesn't help explain how to cache and retrieve images.  It is more like skeleton code to make any general provider.  Again, thank you but it is of minimum help (at least I can see...I am easily confused I guess)

Comment: `"The code doesn't help explain how to cache and retrieve images."` yes, it does, see `_getImage()` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load an Image ahead of being request in the ui with the [`precacheImage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) method. Any future requests for a matching image - the same url in the case of a network image - will pull from the cache. To load a network image, you can pass it an instance of the [`NetworkImage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html) class.

Example:

```
class SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    precacheImage(NetworkImage('someurl.jpg'));
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Certainly looks promising!  The doc notes: _The ImageCache will find the image as long as both images share the same key._  Is there a way to make sure if I use the same URL it is the same key?

Comment: Only the URL has to match

Comment: How can I load images from API?